# Do not show a point symbol for a point if closer than nn meters to another point in same layer

Tags: qgis, point

I have a layer consisting of points (big stones), and there are too many points to be able to show them all in the scale I am using in my print composer.

What is the most efficient, and preferably least processor heavy, way to tell QGIS to only show a point, if there is no other point in the same layer which is closer than, say, 50 meters, from another point in that layer. There is in this case no preference which stone to show and which to not show, ie I have no data telling for instance which stones are bigger or more important.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Point Cluster** symbology.

On the `Layer Properties > Symbology` tab;

1. Select **Point cluster**
2. Change the `Cluster symbol` to make it the same as your original layer.
3. Set Distance to `50.0`
4. Set the Distance Unit to `Map Unit`

[image]

Comment: your Layer Properties dialog suggest that you are using a 3.x version of qgis? I cannot move above version 2.x because of that 3.x seems to lack some of the calculating functions &plugins that my map layout work need. Ihave no Symbology tab, only a Style tab, and no Point cluster point type.